# Crossword using tkinter without classes and objects

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, mysql, tkinter

For my Python project, I wanted to make a crossword game GUI with SQL connectivity to display high scores.  I tried to learn `tkinter`, but the only difficulty was that I cannot use classes or objects as they are not taught at my school yet. Still I managed to make a highly inefficient and ugly looking code (I am a newbie). Please suggest how to improve my code quality and writing style.

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import mysql.connector
import requests
from io import BytesIO


#requesting password to access sql database
passwd = str(input("enter the password for sql database"))

#connecting to mysql
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             user='root',
                                             password=passwd)

#creating database myschool
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myschool''')
cursor.execute('''USE myschool''')

#function to insert player score into database
def updatevalues(val1,val2,val3):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO crossword (User, timetaken, correctvalues) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (val1,val2,val3)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    connection.commit()

#function to create table if crossword table doesnt not exist
def createtable():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE crossword (User varchar(255),timetaken varchar(255),correctvalues int);''')

#defining delete and entry functions
def delete(entry):
    entry.delete(0,'end')
    return None 
    
def entry_get(entry):
    value1 = entry.get()
    return value1

#defining a function to get the entered username
username = ''
def check():
    global username
    if entry_get(nameentry) :
        username = str(entry_get(nameentry))
    delete(nameentry)
    new_window.destroy()


#making a login window
new_window = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(new_window,text='Enter username:',font=('Times New Roman',25)).place(x=80,y=100)
tk.Label(new_window,text='Welcome to My Game',font=('Algerian',35,'underline')).place(x=60,y=10)
tk.Label(new_window,text='Note: The Game will start as soon as you press enter',font=('Times New Roman',15)).place(x=70,y=230)

nameentry = tk.Entry(new_window)
nameentry.place(x=320,y=110,height=30,width=200)

sub1 = tk.Button(new_window,text="Enter", command = check)
sub1.place(x=250,y=160,height=40,width=150)

new_window.geometry('600x350')
new_window.mainloop()


#making the main crossword window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My GUI")
lab = tk.Label(window,text='Crossword#1')
               

               
#making a 30 min timer
def update_timeText():
    if (state):
        global timer
        timer[2] += 1
        if (timer[2] >= 100):
            timer[2] = 0
            timer[1] += 1
        if (timer[1] >= 60):
            timer[0] += 1
            timer[1] = 0
        timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
        timeText.configure(text=timeString)
    if timer == [30,0,0]:
        timeText.configure(text="30:00:00")
    else:
        window.after(10, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state = True
    
def stop():
    global state
    state = False
    
state = False
timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'
timeText = tk.Label(window, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 30))
timeText.place(x=100,y=30)
update_timeText()
window.after(1,start)

#creating a canvas and making a crossword structure
cwidth=450
cheight=450
W = tk.Canvas(window,width=cwidth,height=cheight,highlightbackground='black')
W.place(x=100,y=100)

for i in range(0,450,50):
    W.create_line(0,i,450,i)
    W.create_line(i,0,i,450)

#marking numbers on grid
W.create_text(10,10,text=1)
W.create_text(110,10,text=2)
W.create_text(260,10,text=3)
W.create_text(310,10,text=4)
W.create_text(410,10,text=5)
W.create_text(10,110,text=6)
W.create_text(60,110,text=7)
W.create_text(160,110,text=8)
W.create_text(260,110,text=9)
W.create_text(360,110,text=10)
W.create_text(160,160,text=11)
W.create_text(10,210,text=12)
W.create_text(260,210,text=13)
W.create_text(160,260,text=14)
W.create_text(10,310,text=15)
W.create_text(110,310,text=16)
W.create_text(260,310,text=17)
W.create_text(310,310,text=18)
W.create_text(410,310,text=19)
W.create_text(10,410,text=20)
W.create_text(260,410,text=21)

#making black squares
W.create_rectangle(200,0,250,150,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(150,50,300,100,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(350,50,400,100,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(0,150,50,200,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(100,150,150,200,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(300,150,350,200,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(400,150,451,200,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(200,200,250,250,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(0,250,50,300,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(100,250,150,300,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(300,250,350,300,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(400,250,451,300,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(200,300,250,451,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(50,350,100,400,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(150,350,300,400,fill='black')
W.create_rectangle(350,350,400,400,fill='black')

#creating section for clues
X = tk.Canvas(window,height=600,width=700,highlightbackground='black')
X.pack(padx=40,side='right')

#Across secion
X.create_text(130,50,font=('Arial',40),text='Across')
X.create_text(115,105,font=('Arial',20),text='1. Locale')
X.create_text(176,145,font=('Arial',20),text='3. Soup Containers')
X.create_text(180,185,font=('Arial',20),text='6. Nectar Gatherers')
X.create_text(150,225,font=('Arial',20),text='9. Fries or Slaw')
X.create_text(159,265,font=('Arial',20),text='11. Household pest')
X.create_text(167,305,font=('Arial',20),text='12. Belonging to Eda')
X.create_text(120,345,font=('Arial',20),text='13. __ of Evil')
X.create_text(150,385,font=('Arial',20),text='14. Morning Riser')
X.create_text(100,425,font=('Arial',20),text='15. Lazily')
X.create_text(138,465,font=('Arial',20),text='17. Buck or doe')
X.create_text(167,505,font=('Arial',20),text='20. Sunrise direction')
X.create_text(195,545,font=('Arial',19),text='21. you do this with a book')

#Down section
X.create_text(530,50,font=('Arial',40),text='Down')
X.create_text(520,105,font=('Arial',20),text='1. Long Sandwhich')
X.create_text(487,145,font=('Arial',20),text='2. Casual top')
X.create_text(471,185,font=('Arial',20),text='4. __ Baba')
X.create_text(471,225,font=('Arial',20),text='5. Observe')
X.create_text(484,265,font=('Arial',20),text='7. Concluded')
X.create_text(465,305,font=('Arial',20),text='8. Cheeky')
X.create_text(465,345,font=('Arial',20),text='9. Dont sit')
X.create_text(457,385,font=('Arial',20),text='10. Tee off')
X.create_text(516,425,font=('Arial',20),text='15. If__I said it once')
X.create_text(480,465,font=('Arial',20),text='16. __Angeles')
X.create_text(498,505,font=('Arial',20),text='18. New Years__')
X.create_text(530,545,font=('Arial',20),text='19. Scarlett or Maroon')

#linking tick image when answer is correct
img_url = "https://i.ibb.co/2PKKZrj/iconfinder-tick-16-22643.png"
response = requests.get(img_url)
img_data = response.content
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(img_data)))

def tickimg(x_co,y_co):
    panel = tk.Label(window, image=img)
    panel.place(x=x_co,y=y_co)


lis = [['1','A','site'],['1','D','sub'],['2','D','tee'],['3','A','cans'],['4','D','ali'],
       ['5','D','see'],['6','A','bees'],['7','D','ended'],['8','D','sassy'],
       ['9','A','side'],['9','D','stand'],['10','D','drive'],['11','A','ant'],['12','A','idas'],
       ['13','A','axis'],['14','A','sun'],['15','A','idly'],['15','D','ive'],
       ['16','D','los'],['17','A','deer'],['18','D','eve'],
       ['19','D','red'],['20','A','east'],['21','A','read']]

def listchange():
    stop()
    global timer
    timestring = ''
    minutes = timer[0]
    if minutes < 10:
        timestring += '0'+str(timer[0])+':'
    else:
        timestring += str(timer[0])+':'
    seconds = timer[1]
    if seconds < 10:    
        timestring += '0'+str(timer[1])+':'
    else:
        timestring += str(timer[1])+':'
    milliseconds = timer[2]
    if milliseconds < 10:    
        timestring += '0'+str(timer[2])
    else:
        timestring += str(timer[2])
    return timestring

def button_fun():
    global correct
    global username
    new_timer = listchange()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""show tables;""")
    if ('crossword',) in cursor:
        updatevalues(username,new_timer,len(correct))
    else:
        createtable()
        updatevalues(username,new_timer,len(correct))
        
def endscreen1():    
    root = tk.Tk()
    def des():
        root.destroy()
    root.geometry('700x450')
    tk.Label(root,text='THANK YOU',font=('Algerian',60)).place(x = 140,y = 30)
    tk.Label(root,text='FOR',font=('Algerian',60)).place(x = 270, y = 120)
    tk.Label(root,text='PLAYING',font=('Algerian',60)).place(x = 190, y= 210)
    viewscore = tk.Button(root,text='VIEW HIGHSCORE',command=des)
    viewscore.place(x=270,y=340,height=40,width=150)
    root.mainloop()


    
def highscore():   
    newroot = tk.Tk()
    newroot.geometry('800x700')  
    tk.Label(newroot,text='HIGH SCORES',font=('Algerian',50,'underline')).pack(side='top',pady=20)
    Y = tk.Canvas(newroot,height=700,width=600,highlightbackground='black')
    Y.pack(side='top',pady=30)
    Y.create_line(200,0,200,700)
    Y.create_line(400,0,400,700)
    Y.create_text(100,30,text='Name',font=('Times New Roman',30))
    Y.create_text(300,30,text='Time Taken',font=('Times New Roman',30))
    Y.create_text(500,30,text='Correct',font=('Times New Roman',30))
    Y.create_text(500,60,text='Answers',font=('Times New Roman',30))
    Y.create_line(0,80,600,80)
   
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''select * from crossword order by correctvalues desc,timetaken ;''')
    
    names = []
    times = []
    correct = []
    for i in cursor:
        names.append(i[0])
        times.append(i[1])
        correct.append(i[2])
        
    x1_co = 100
    x2_co = 300
    x3_co = 500
    y_co = 60
    if len(names) > 8:
        names = names[0:8]
    for i in range(0,len(names)):
        y_co += 50
        Y.create_text(x1_co,y_co,text=names[i],font=('Times New Roman',20))
        Y.create_text(x2_co,y_co,text=times[i],font=('Times New Roman',20))
        Y.create_text(x3_co,y_co,text=correct[i],font=('Times New Roman',20))
    
    newroot.mainloop()
  
correct = []
def check_func(myvav = False):
    global correct
    global isclicked
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if entry_get(entry1) == lis[i][0] and entry_get(entry2) == lis[i][1] and entry_get(entry3) == lis[i][2]:
            correct.append('1')
            if i == 0:
                tickimg(640,160)

                W.create_text(25,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(75,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(125,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='T')
                W.create_text(175,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 1:

                tickimg(980,160)
                W.create_text(25,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(25,75,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='U')
                W.create_text(25,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='B')
                
            if i == 2:

                tickimg(980,200)
                W.create_text(125,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='T')
                W.create_text(125,75,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(125,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 3:

                tickimg(640,200)
                W.create_text(275,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='C')
                W.create_text(325,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(375,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='N')
                W.create_text(425,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                
            if i == 4:

                tickimg(980,240)
                W.create_text(325,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(325,75,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='L')
                W.create_text(325,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                
            if i == 5:

                tickimg(980,280)
                W.create_text(425,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(425,75,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(425,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 6:


                tickimg(640,240)
                W.create_text(25,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='B')
                W.create_text(75,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(125,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(175,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                
            if i == 7:

                tickimg(980,320)
                W.create_text(75,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(75,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='N')
                W.create_text(75,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                W.create_text(75,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(75,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                
            if i == 8:

                tickimg(980,360)
                W.create_text(175,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(175,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(175,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(175,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(175,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='Y')
                
            if i == 9:

                tickimg(640,280)
                W.create_text(275,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(325,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(375,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                W.create_text(425,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 10:

                tickimg(980,400)
                W.create_text(275,125,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(275,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='T')
                W.create_text(275,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(275,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='N')
                W.create_text(275,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D') 
                
            if i == 11:

                tickimg(980,440)
                W.create_text(275,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                W.create_text(375,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='R')
                W.create_text(375,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(375,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='V')
                W.create_text(375,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 12:

                tickimg(625,320)
                W.create_text(175,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(225,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='N')
                W.create_text(275,175,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='T')
                
            if i == 13:

                tickimg(627,360)
                W.create_text(25,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(75,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                W.create_text(125,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(175,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                
            if i == 14:

                tickimg(627,400)
                W.create_text(275,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(325,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='X')
                W.create_text(375,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(425,225,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                
                
            if i == 15:

                tickimg(627,440)
                W.create_text(175,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(225,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='U')
                W.create_text(275,275,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='N')
                
            if i == 16:

                tickimg(627,480)
                W.create_text(25,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(75,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                W.create_text(125,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='L')
                W.create_text(175,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='Y')
                
            if i == 17:


                tickimg(980,480)
                W.create_text(25,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
                W.create_text(25,375,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='V')
                W.create_text(25,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 18:

                tickimg(980,520)
                W.create_text(125,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='L')
                W.create_text(125,375,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='O')
                W.create_text(125,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                
            if i == 19:

                tickimg(627,520)
                W.create_text(275,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                W.create_text(325,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(375,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(425,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='R')
                
            if i == 20:

                tickimg(980,560)
                W.create_text(325,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(325,375,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='V')
                W.create_text(325,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                
            if i == 21:

                tickimg(980,600)
                W.create_text(425,325,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='R')
                W.create_text(425,375,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(425,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')
                
            if i == 22:

                tickimg(627,560)
                W.create_text(25,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(75,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(125,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
                W.create_text(175,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='T')
                
            if i == 23:

                tickimg(627,600)
                W.create_text(275,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='R')
                W.create_text(325,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
                W.create_text(375,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='A')
                W.create_text(425,425,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='D')

    delete(entry1)
    delete(entry2)
    delete(entry3)
    
    if myvav == True:
        submitbutton.bind('<Button-1>',button_fun())
        window.destroy()
        endscreen1()
        highscore()
        
    if len(correct) == 24:
        button_fun()
        window.destroy()
        endscreen1()
        highscore()

#Entry windows ,check button and submit button
tk.Label(window,text='Number:',font=('Arial',15)).place(x=21,y=580)
entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
entry1.place(x=100,y=580,height=30,width=100)

tk.Label(window,text='A or D:',font=('Arial',15)).place(x=230,y=580)
entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
entry2.place(x=300,y=580,height=30,width=100)

tk.Label(window,text='Word:',font=('Arial',15)).place(x=437,y=580)
entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
entry3.place(x=500,y=580,height=30,width=100)

check_button = tk.Button(window,
                   text="Check",command=check_func)
check_button.place(x=270,y=630,height=30,width=100)

submitbutton = tk.Button(window,text="Submit",command=lambda: check_func(myvav=True))
submitbutton.place(x=500,y=630,height=30,width=100)

window.geometry("1366x768")

window.mainloop()
```

One more thing: I want to add data file handling in this, but I am not quite sure how that works.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Yep, you're right, the code looks ugly. Since you already know how to define functions with parameters, why didn't you use them for the repetitive `W.create_text` blocks? For example you could define `add_across(627, 560, 25, 425, "EAST")` or `add_down(980, 600, 425, 325, "RED")`. As long as there are no answers, you may still improve your code.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks for the advice. I will definitely implement this on my code.

Answer (score 1):

### Efficiency

In the `for` loop in the `check_func` function, you check the `i` variable
24 times every time through the loop because you have 24 separate
`if` statements:

```
        if i == 0:
        
        if i == 1:
        
        ...

        if i == 23:
```

The code would be more efficient with a single `if/elif/elif...` statement:

```
        if i == 0:
        
        elif i == 1:
        
        ...

        elif i == 23:
```

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

In the `check_func` function, you set the same font many times:

```
            W.create_text(25,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='S')
            W.create_text(75,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='I')
            W.create_text(125,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='T')
            W.create_text(175,25,font=('Times New Roman',25),text='E')
```

At a minimum, you could create a variable to pass to the `create_text`
call for the font.

There may be other opportunities here to wrap those calls into a
function if there is some commonality among the numbers you pass in.

### Layout

The assignment to the `lis` variable is hard to understand.  It would be
easier to understand if you had one array per line, for example:

```
lis = [
        ['1','A','site'],
        ['1','D','sub'],
        ['2','D','tee'],
```

I recommend moving the functions to the top, after the `import` statements.
Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the
code (from a human readability standpoint).

### Comments

Some comments are not needed because they simply repeat what the
code does:

```
#connecting to mysql
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
```

### Naming

Some variable and function names are not very meaningful:

```
lis
myvav
check
check_func
```

### Documentation

You could add usage information as comments at the top of the file.
State the purpose of the code along with the required input and the
expected output.